# Spring boot jpa, composition - how to find an object with a property from another class

Tags: java, jpa, associations, composition

I'm trying to write an basic registration/login module for my app with Spring boot JPA. The problem is that I'm using a composition:

```
public class Person {

    private int personID;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    // Constructors, getters and setters ommited for brevity
}


public class User {
    
    private int buyerID;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private Person person;
    
    // Other fields, getters and setters ommited for brevity
    
}
```

Now I want to find an User by email. I have repositories interfaces extending JpaRepository and:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

    Person findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Of course there can be only one Person associated with the User. I cannot figure out how to find out which User is connected with which email address.

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this ..
I supposed that the person refrence in user table is called `id_person`, otherwise you put the right names

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT p.* from person p inner join user u on p.id=u.id_person where u.email = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
 Person findByEmail(String email);
```

Comment: It didn't help me in that case, but it'll be useful later. I found my mistake in the code thanks to you